# How to detect the Usercontroller error from imported aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, ascx

I am import many usercontroller's(ascx) in a single aspx page and if any one of the Usercontroller having error, total usercontroller(ascx) will not load. How can I detect the problematic usercontroller.

Currently I am solve this problem by the below way

I will hide all the user controller one by one and find the problematic usercontroller.

Comment: "any one of the Usercontroller having error" - are you loading them with Page.LoadControl ?

Comment: @Dexion may be chance to error occur.

Answer (score 0):

Errors during Page.LoadControl can be handled with try .. catch .